# unable to read input file as a property list

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

Trying to work out why I am getting the following error.

```
unable to read input file as a property list: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 1.)
```

It's after this line

```
CopyPlistFile /Users/russellharrower/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DRN1-fhqxqayjahfwlkaxifrlezidyiun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DRN1.app/Entitlements.plist /Users/russellharrower/Apps/vscroll/vscroll/Entitlements.plist (in target 'DRN1' from project 'DRN1')
    cd /Users/russellharrower/Apps/vscroll
    builtin-copyPlist --convert binary1 --outdir /Users/russellharrower/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DRN1-fhqxqayjahfwlkaxifrlezidyiun/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DRN1.app -- /Users/russellharrower/Apps/vscroll/vscroll/Entitlements.plist
```

This is to get CarPlay working.

Entitlements.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.carplay-audio</key>
    <true/>
<dict/>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it’s not valid xml. Change the next-to-last line:

```
<dict/>
```

To:

```
</dict>
```